# Force fancyhdr headheight same on all pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancyhdr` to create a header with two lines in `lhead` and two lines in `rhead` like so,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{lhead line 1 \\ lhead line 2}
\rhead{rhead line 1 \\ rhead line 2}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The **problem** is:

- On the first page, the distance between the header and the paragraph text doesn't change when a multi-line `\lhead` or multi-line `\rhead` is used. However, one subsequent pages, the distance adjusts properly

I've attached pictures showing what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Notice that there is a difference between the headheight on the different pages. I want the first page header to be like the second, ... page header.

Comment: There is a warning in the log file: "\headheight is too small (12.0pt):  Make it at least 27.18335pt.  We now make it that large for the rest of the document.  This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however." So use `\usepackage[margin=1.0in,headheight=27.18335pt]{geometry}` or a larger value for `headheight`.

Comment: @esdd Can you make that an official answer or mark as duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by esdd, this problem can be dealt with by passing the `headheight=27.18335pt` option to the `geometry` package. The `27.18335pt` value is suggested by the log file.

```
\usepackage[margin=1.0in,headheight=27.18335pt]{geometry}
```